# textInputBox.layer.borderColor not working from the code

Tags: ios, xcode, border

```
//sample problem
myInputTextBox.layer.borderColor= CFBridgingRetain([UIColor grayColor]); //not working
myInputTextBox.layer.borderColor= [UIColor grayColor];          //implicit conversion, not working
myInputTextBox.layer.borderColor= (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor grayColor]);//not working
```

I spend, pretty good time. application,myInputTextBox is UITextField object. Please help me to fix this problem in Xcode for IOS

```
//Actual code is 
UITextField *_PI[6];
for(int i=0;i<totalChances;i++){
    _PI[i]=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(15,55, 50,30), 49*i,0)];
    _PI[i].placeholder=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"P(%c)",(i+'A')];
    _PI[i].Delegate=self;
    _PI[i].font=fontInputs;
    _PI[i].borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleLine;
    _PI[i].layer.borderWidth=0.5f;//even if i change the border width to 2.0, it does not work
    _PI[i].layer.borderColor= (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor grayColor]);//this line doesn't works
    [self.view addSubview:_PI[i]];
}
```

Comment: did you checked myInputTextBox is bind to any object in UI?

Comment: no, it is not. Is this the problem with binding? Actually I don't know what is bind.

Comment: did you set it's IBOUtlet?

Comment: binding mean you've bind an object from interface builder to         myInputTextBox or programmatically added it in view by setting frame

Comment: I've updated the question with my actual code. I'm not sure if I have used binding

Comment: try to put any other colour like red or green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting border width

```
 myInputTextBox.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```

edit:

Modify your code as:

```
    UITextField *_PI[6];
    for(int i=0;i<totalChances;i++){
        _PI[i]=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(15,55, 50,30), 49*i,0)];
        _PI[i].placeholder=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"P(%c)",(i+'A')];
        _PI[i].delegate=self; // you had 'd' capital
        _PI[i].font=fontInputs;
        _PI[i].borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleLine;
        _PI[i].layer.borderWidth=5.5f;//even if i change the border width to 2.0, it does not work
        _PI[i].layer.borderColor= [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;//this line doesn't works
        [self.view addSubview:_PI[i]];
    }
```

Comment: I have used myInputTextBox.layer.borderWidth= 0.5f; let me check if that is my problem

Comment: I changed the width once to 2.0 and once to 2.0f. neither one works.

Comment: not working. nothing works. Just black color box only